# Python socket not reading multiple lines

Tags: python, sockets, encoding, tcpserver

I have below python code snippet that acts as TCP server. The problem is when I try to send multiple lines from client one by one I am receiving only the first line and after that TCP server is sending RST(I verified this in wireshark) whereas if I send multiple lines at one shot I am receiving all of them.

```
class SyslogTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        total_data = []
        while True:
            data = self.request.recv(8192).strip().decode("ascii")
            if not data:
                break
            print("LOG: {}".format(data))

def open_tcp_syslog_server():
    try:
        server = socketserver.TCPServer(('0.0.0.0', 5143), SyslogTCPHandler)
        server.serve_forever(poll_interval=1)
    except (IOError, SystemExit):
        raise
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logger.info ("Crtl+C Pressed. Shutting down.")

open_tcp_syslog_server()
```

Below is the TCP client that I am using,
[image]

If I uncheck "Send One message per Line Feed" then it works fine. One more thing to note is that if I change the encoding to "UTF8" from ASCII then its working fine.

Any idea on how what's happening?

Comment: Not sure if this completely explains the problem, but you should be doing the `if not data:` check *before* applying `.strip()`.  If a received packet consists entirely of characters that will be stripped, `data` becomes an empty string, and your server drops the connection.

Comment: if that is the case, it should have raised exceptions right instead of silently sending TCP RST...anyways will check that out thanks

Comment: I doubt very many people know how or what your client is doing, but that would seem to be important for understanding what's not working. Also, technically your server receive processing code is incorrect, though it likely will work fine if whatever you're sending only uses one byte per character like ASCII.